# how to remove vpn notification in android app

Tags: android

I'm making an app for school block URL via VPN (VPN service) 
and this app is secured via password but
there is VPN notification with lock icon I can't get rid of it
is there any way via notification or admin access to prevent the user from closing my VPN outside the app

```
 private void setupVPN() {
        if (vpnInterface == null) {
            Builder builder = new Builder();
            builder.addAddress(VPN_ADDRESS, 32);
            builder.addRoute(VPN_ROUTE, 0);
            VPN_DNS=getString(R.string.dns_server);
            Log.d(TAG,"use dns:"+VPN_DNS);
            builder.addRoute(VPN_DNS, 32);
            builder.addDnsServer(VPN_DNS);
            builder.setConfigureIntent(pendingIntent);
            vpnInterface =builder.establish();
            vpnInterface = builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name)).setConfigureIntent(pendingIntent).establish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> there is Vpn notification with lock icon i can't get rid of it

There is a status bar icon showing VPN usage. It is important that users understand that a VPN app is monitoring their Internet communications.

> is there any way via notification or admin access to prevent the user from closing my vpn outside the app

[`setAlwaysOnVpnPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setAlwaysOnVpnPackage(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) is available to device owner or profile owner apps, but not device admin apps or ordinary apps.

Comment: thank you after some search  
 device owner is rooted device 
and profile owner is for  N+ connected to google profile the school apps   are L version and they are not rooted 
So there is no way to prevent  the user from disconnect

Comment: @aymenlabidi: "device owner is rooted device" -- no, the device owner app is an app set up by the IT manager who sets up the devices after purchase.